# How to display the blue warning message box of Windows In Python?

Tags: python

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION :**

I want to generate the blue message box of Windows. The message box where it's writen "you'll be disconnected".

I tried this code but it give me a different one (it's still a warning but that's not the message box I wanted) A good thing I know ctypes is the library to work with

**CODE :**

```
import ctypes 

message_box_title = "Warning"
message_box_text = "You will be disconnected in 30 seconds"
message_box_flags = 0x00001030  


ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, message_box_text, message_box_title, message_box_flags)
```

That's a message box like this but with the message of disconnection soon like in x number of seconds/minutes

[image: publisher]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows you the message boxes provided by ctypes:

```
import ctypes

styles = {
    "MB_OK": 0x00000000,
    "MB_OKCANCEL": 0x00000001,
    "MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE": 0x00000002,
    "MB_YESNOCANCEL": 0x00000003,
    "MB_YESNO": 0x00000004,
    "MB_RETRYCANCEL": 0x00000005,
    "MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE": 0x00000006,
    "MB_HELP": 0x00004000,
    "MB_ICONHAND": 0x00000010,
    "MB_ICONQUESTION": 0x00000020,
    "MB_ICONEXCLAMATION": 0x00000030,
    "MB_ICONASTERISK": 0x00000040,
    "MB_USERICON": 0x00000080,
    "MB_ICONWARNING": 0x00000030,
    "MB_ICONERROR": 0x00000010,
    "MB_ICONINFORMATION": 0x00000040,
    "MB_ICONSTOP": 0x00000010,
    "MB_DEFBUTTON1": 0x00000000,
    "MB_DEFBUTTON2": 0x00000100,
    "MB_DEFBUTTON3": 0x00000200,
    "MB_DEFBUTTON4": 0x00000300,
    "MB_TOPMOST": 0x00040000,
    "MB_SETFOREGROUND": 0x00010000,
    "MB_RIGHT": 0x00080000,
    "MB_RTLREADING": 0x00100000
}

for name, value in styles.items():
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, f"This is a message box with style {name}", "Message Box Styles", value)
```

You can't get the message box from your image because ctypes is limited to providing access to the message box styles that are available through the Windows API.
You may need to consider creating your own message box using a GUI toolkit like Tkinter, PyQt, or wxPython.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for clarifying it. So I can't access the message box I provided above ? What if I don't use ctypes ?

Comment: I don't really think you can. But maybe a toast notification helps you, check out the `win10toast` library.